# How to remove Customize from admin menu bar after WP 4.3

Tags: functions, admin-menu, theme-customizer

WordPress 4.3 brought more updates to the customizer. It also added a new option at the top admin menu bar that says 'Cusomize' and has a paintbrush. How can I disable this menu from showing up? We don't use the customizer, and I would not like our users clicking on it either.

We currently do `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');` but I do not know the term for the customizer. I tried both customize and customizer (guessing) but neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`customize` should work. I was able to remove the Customize link with the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse200296_before_admin_bar_render' ); 

function wpse200296_before_admin_bar_render()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('customize');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Or this more compact one will do the same :

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_some_nodes_from_admin_top_bar_menu', 999 );
function remove_some_nodes_from_admin_top_bar_menu( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'customize' );
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the solutions posted here worked for me. Instead I used the following:

```
/**
 * Remove elements from sidebar.
 */
function remove_customize_from_admin_sidebar() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fthemes.php' );

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_customize_from_admin_sidebar' );
```

This uses the [remove_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/) function to specify the parent link (themes.php) and then the child link - in this case the Customize URL.

If you want to remove parent menu items, you can use [remove_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_menu_page/), for example:

```
remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
```